# Read xls file from a URL in python

Tags: python, pandas, xls

I'm trying to read data from the link below in python
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16cp23cJxeyUfnBHMp-sNCuFNQxe8cqOV/view

**I've tried this:**

`import pandas as pd`

`path = pd.read_excel('https://drive.google.com/file/d/16cp23cJxeyUfnBHMp-sNCuFNQxe8cqOV/view')`

**That returned this error:**

XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<!DOCTYP'

**Then I tried using cvs format**

`path = pd.read_csv('https://drive.google.com/file/d/16cp23cJxeyUfnBHMp-sNCuFNQxe8cqOV/view')`

**Returned this**

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 298 fields in line 133, saw 440

finnaly I tried this:

```
path = pd.read_csv("https://drive.google.com/file/d/16cp23cJxeyUfnBHMp-sNCuFNQxe8cqOV/view")
```

This read data but that is not what I expected after seen the link (283 rows, 7 columns). Photo below.

[Error reading data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G78OO.png)

Any ideas of how could I read the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this example to download the excel from Google Drive (the `fileid` is the ID after the `/d/` part in your URL):

```py
fileid = "16cp23cJxeyUfnBHMp-sNCuFNQxe8cqOV"

df = pd.read_excel(
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={fileid}".format(
        fileid=fileid
    ),
    skiprows=17,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Unnamed: 0                                         Unnamed: 1                                         Unnamed: 2 Petajoules Gigajoules           %
0           NaN                                        Afghanistan                                        Afghanistan        321         10   78.669280
1           NaN                                            Albania                                            Albania        102         35  100.000000
2           NaN                                            Algeria                                            Algeria       1959         51    0.551010
3           NaN                                     American Samoa                                     American Samoa        ...        ...    0.641026
4           NaN                                            Andorra                                            Andorra          9        121   88.695650
5           NaN                                             Angola                                             Angola        642         27   70.909090

...and so on.
```